# Need help replacing bulb in fancy light fixture

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

How do I remove/open this Light fixture to replace the bulb? [image: Photo of Light Fixture]

Comment: Better photos, please, particularly of the end and top.

Comment: think about it this way: The manufacturer made that thing so you could replace a bulb.  Maybe the bar swings up to release the glass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were small screws on the both sides of the metal, top and bottom (4 total) that was securing the glass attached to the metal frame. Removing them provided access. You have to remove 4 tiny screws and dangle sharp edged glass, while perched up on the bathroom counter top. Not losing the tiny screw is another challenge with screw driver on one hand, glass on another .... thanks for the responses everyone!

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  You can accept your own answer (click the checkmark next to it), which will indicate that the problem is solved and there is a proven solution here.